# MVC4: After recycling Application Pool Error: Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My MVC4 application always have this error:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

every time my application pool restarted.

If I clear my browser cookies and cache it works again without no error. I already set my application to store the session in SQLServer.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=State;Integrated Security=False;User ID=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" cookieless="false" timeout="2880" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" />
```

I already check my state database, and it stores the value so I think the storing session to my database is working.

So why is this happening? Every time I recycle my App Pool, this weird error keeps showing up.

Note: If I use `Chrome's Incognito Mode`, everything is fine. I guess there is something to do with my cookies or cache which causes this.

Comment: Consider using either `LocalSystem` or `NetworkService` account instead of `ApplicationPoolIdentity` on Process Model Identity section. Or else, you may try adding `IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0` user into SSMS login.

Comment: I change it into `NetworkService` my website is running well after the server is restarted, but the website redirects me into `login page`. The weirdest thing is that the website redirects me to login page, but actually my authentication is not lost. I am still logged on as the user before the server restarted. Why the website even redirected me into `login page` when my authentication still valid? I just refreshed the page which requires registered user, which I am still logged on. Could you help me explain what is going on?

Comment: I'm not sure how you "restarted" the server: by application pool recycling, restarting site or hard reset? Restarting site or recycling app pool with IIS Manager often doesn't revoke authenticated users at the time of either actions performed, as long as they have valid cookies.

Comment: I mean "restarted" is recycled.